# Working GAS, now executing out of order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Script that gathers data from a Google Spreadsheet, compiles that data, adds a cover page, exports a PDF of the newly created packet, and then cleans itself up.  The script has been working flawlessly for two years, but a couple of months ago it started executing out of order.  Instead of finishing with copying all of the data to the temporary sheet, the script now performs the export to PDF portion before it finishes the last sheet.  It's always the last sheet that gets left off, no matter how many sheets are in the queue.  The script will then fill in the information for that final sheet, but since the export has already run, the information does not make it into the PDF.

I did not change anything about the script before it stopped working.  Since it stopped working, I have cleaned some things up in troubleshooting, but nothing has changed the behavior.  I have tried using the lock() function, but that did not solve the issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide any clarifying information.

(Also, ignore that the total on the estimate sheet is wrong, there is a minimum value assigned to that cell.)

Here is the output that the script now generates:[Current output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14-uJcZ5xZ3SC9jha3SoBqh5b49777sLe)

Here is the expected output (generated with the script, but exported manually by printing to PDF): [Manuall Export](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ilmzlE-65CA-UqLcCSN4L9A85a7U_EZF)

```js
function exportMultipleFullSheets() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hopper = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Export Setup");
  var cover = ss.getSheetByName("Cover Sheet");
  var namesToProcess = hopper.getRange(2, 1, 10, 1).getValues()
  var sheetsToProcess = new Array(10);
  Logger.log(sheetsToProcess);
  //Get the first of the sheets to be processed, which is where the cover sheet data is mostly pulled from.
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName(namesToProcess[0][0]);

  var producer = ts.getRange("K31").getValue();
  var contact = ts.getRange("K5").getValue();
  var showName = ts.getRange("F1").getValue();

  //Set up the temporary sheet, which will be exported then deleted
  var tempSheet = ss.insertSheet(showName + " Cost Estimate", 5, {
    template: cover
  });
  
  //Format column widths to correct size for printing
  var cw = 94; //Column Width

  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(1, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(2, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(3, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(4, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(5, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(6, cw);
  tempSheet.setColumnWidth(7, cw);
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(18, 10);
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(18, 1);
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(32, 1);

  tempSheet.setRowHeight(1, 20);

  //Initialize the arrays
  var numCreated = 0;
  var dates = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  var guarantees = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  var descriptions = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  //For each sheet entered in the setup page, grab the relevant data and store it into the correct array. 
  var NTPIO;
  for (var i = 9; i > -1; i--) {
    NTPIO = ss.getSheetByName(namesToProcess[i][0]);
    if (NTPIO != null) {
      dates[i] = NTPIO.getRange("B1").getValue();
      guarantees[i] = NTPIO.getRange("I37").getValue();
      descriptions[i] = NTPIO.getRange("N31").getValue();

      tempSheet.insertColumnsAfter(7, 10);

      Logger.log(namesToProcess[i][0]);

      //resize the newly added columns to be correct for printing
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(8, 15);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(9, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(10, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(11, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(12, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(13, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(14, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(15, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(16, 80);
      tempSheet.setColumnWidth(17, 15);
      NTPIO.getRange("A1:J37").copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("H1:Q37"), {
        formatOnly: true
      });
      NTPIO.getRange("A1:J37").copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("H1:Q37"), {
        contentsOnly: true
      });
      numCreated++;
    }
  }

  tempSheet.getRange("C8").setValue(producer);
  tempSheet.getRange("C9").setValue(contact);
  tempSheet.getRange("C11").setValue(showName);

  //Copy the data from the arrays into the relevant cells in the temporary sheet.
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    tempSheet.getRange(15 + i, 2).setValue(dates[i]);
    tempSheet.getRange(15 + i, 4).setValue(guarantees[i]);
    tempSheet.getRange(15 + i, 5).setValue(descriptions[i]);
  }
  tempSheet.getRange("D15:D24").setNumberFormat("$0.00");

  //Final Height Adjustments
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(2, 10);
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(32, 1);
  tempSheet.setRowHeight(1, 20);


  var url = ss.getUrl();
  url = url.replace(/edit$/, '');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf
    +
    '&size=letter' // paper size
    +
    '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +
    '&fitw=false' // fit to width, false for actual size     
    +
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +
    '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var sheetname = tempSheet.getName();
  var date = sheetname.slice(0, sheetname.indexOf(" "));

  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs = [];

  Logger.log(url + url_ext + tempSheet.getSheetId());

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + tempSheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  var output = response.getBlob().setName(sheetname + '.pdf');

  //Add file to the drive app. 
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(Utilities.formatDate(dates[0], "(GMT-05:00)", "MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + sheetname);

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
  folder.addFile(file);

  //Clean up after you're done.
  ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing writes then reads/exports, make sure all the writes finish first by calling `flush()`

Comment: This appears to have solved the issue!  Thanks!  No idea why it changed suddenly, but happy to have it work.